# React - eval'ing event handlers within child component's scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, eval, scoping

My app contains two components: 'Parent' and 'Child':

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Parent() {
  const t = "Parent";
  return (
    <div className="Parent">
      <Child
        content={
          <button type="button" onClick={() => eval("console.log(t);")}>
            Show t
          </button>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  const t = "Child";
  return props.content;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Parent />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[**Link to Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/eval-with-nested-component-pt4h6)

Parent passes some content to Child and Child renders it. In my example, the content is a button. This button has an onClick handler that prints the value of some variable `t` when it is clicked. For reasons beyond my control, the handler uses `eval` and is evaluated within the Parent component's scope (if you click the button, you can see that it logs "Parent", which is the value of `t` inside the Parent component). **However, I need to scope `t` within the Child's scope (so that it logs "Child" when the button is clicked). Is there a way to do this?**

I'm not very clear on JS scoping rules but as I understand it, eval has local scope when called directly. But Child's content is not known to me beforehand so I can't call it inside Child itself. Also, I cannot avoid using eval altogether since the handler will always be passed to the component as a string.

---

**EDIT:** I can use `React.cloneElement` to wrap the handler in eval inside the Child component like so:

```
function Child(props) {
  const t = "Child";
  return React.cloneElement(props.content, {onClick: eval(props.content.props.onClick)});
}
```

This works but is untenable if content has nested components - I would have to recurse through them and it gets messy.

Comment: why not specify the button inside child component?

Comment: @Ashu, the Child component is just a wrapper component, its content can be anything and is not known to me in advance.

Comment: Probably then you've found the best way you would achieve this tho, you can paste the solution to your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make a `content` to be a function of variable `t` and then call it inside the component with scope of which you want to associate that variable?
I mean something like below code:

```
function Parent() {
  const t = "Parent";
  return (
    <div className="Parent">
      <Child
        content={(
           t // <-------------------- note that it is a function now
        ) => (
          <button type="button" onClick={() => eval("console.log(t);")}>
            Show t
          </button>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  const t = "Child";
  return props.content(t); // <--------------------- calling it here, so it see t from child component
}
```

> EDIT: I can use React.cloneElement to wrap the handler in eval inside the Child component
> This works but is untenable if content has nested components - I would have to recurse >through them and it gets messy.

It also should not cause problem with recursion, because variable `t`, that you would pass to that function will be in scope of that function, so all components created there should see it ( like it is happening now with your `Child` component, which see variable from `Parent`'s scope.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Bohdan. I can pass a function to props.content but it would have to be in the form of a string. In my actual app, the value of props.content is an object with properties name, attributes and children. Inside Child, I recursively apply React.createElement to this object to transform it into a React element. Are you able to suggest an alternative approach that uses this object?

Comment: I was thinking I could flag properties that require eval so that I can identify and eval those props when I'm applying React.createElement to the props.content object in Child. Here is a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eval-with-nested-component-pt4h6?file=/src/index.js) that better illustrates the problem. I'm using `call` to pass `t` to the function that calls React.createElement. This works but now the `onClick` callback must use the `this` keyword to reference `t`, i.e. `'() => {console.log(this.t}'`.

Comment: Sorry, for such late response, but I wasn't near my computer because of holidays.
I managed to create an example where I am not using this
https://codesandbox.io/s/eval-with-nested-component-forked-xpm5m?file=/src/index.js

Instead of that, i am stringifying object called scope and creating a new function as a an onClick handler. 
Notice, also that I used window.Function instead of eval, because as it written in docs, it is faster and more safer than eval. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Comment: Also notice, that I changed name of onClick in your original object to onClickHandler, because when I used onClick, there was a strange loop and window.Function(same as eval), instead of see original method saw method, that i defined as an onclick handler inside hydrate function.